# How to disable PrtScr

Tags: security, screenshot

I'm working on a program that operates like a TOTP protocol. The program is giving the user passwords to other applications every 30 seconds. For security reasons, I want to be able to block the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key and similar screen capture methods. Does anyone have any idea how I can prevent this? I am working with Windows programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is incredibly vague and provides no context or research, but here goes:

You cannot *completely* prevent screen capture programs (like snipping tool or OBS) from capturing your software on a screen. However, here's a couple of ways you can prevent the printscreen tool in windows.

**Method 1: Disable unwanted keystrokes**

You can read the Windows API to disable unwanted keystrokes. [This CodeProject documentation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante) should show you how to do it in C#.

**Method 2: Hide your application**

You can use something similar to this to hide your application on screen so if the PrintScreen button is pressed, it will hide your application (and thus hide the password(s) on screen) from the screenshot.

```
private void Display_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Snapshot)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Please note that this piece of code is not *guaranteed* to fix the problem. Use it as an idea or template to build your own methods of hiding the window.

---

If you are still absolutely desperate, you can change the software to show a button that says "Copy Password to Clipboard". Instead of displaying the password in a textbox, the user can see a label like "Amazon Account" and then click on the button that says to copy their password to the clipboard. This means the actual password is never revealed on screen yet the user can still copy and paste it into their Amazon account etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be developing a TOTP client on a system that is also used as the main system to authenticate. If it is a different system, then you should not care about prntscrn at all.